# HTML Select w/ weekdays, today selected

Tags: html, date, selection, getdate

I have a select menu with the weekdays. I would like this menu to have todays day selected. From W3Cschools, I got this simple code for getting an int for todays date:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
```

This would output a 3, since it's wednesday. My problem here is to make the specific day in the list selected. Here is my code for the sropdown:

```
<div class="matmenu">
<select id="selectDagMat" ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="wilink/mandag">Måndag</option>
<option value="wilink/tisdag">Tisdag</option>
<option value="wilink/onsdag">Onsdag</option>
<option value="wilink/torsdag">Torsdag</option>
<option value="wilink/fredag">Fredag</option>
<option value="wilink/lordag">Lördag</option>
<option selected="selected" value="wilink/sondag">Söndag</option>
</select>
```

Also, an example of the page can be found here:

http://stilius.se/wilink/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xuPz2/1/ ? You get the element via `getElementById` and then you set the value.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I need the value to be the path due to my onChange function. Or is it possible to use [this.selectedIndex].name and change the name to the path?

Comment: Hi, One simple solution you could do is by simply using the switch statement: http://jsfiddle.net/xuPz2/2/